# Is Anushasan Parva from Mahabharat an interpolation? It is claimed by many scholars and also it is not mentioned in the spitzer manuscript

Tags: mahabharata, history, sri-vaishnava

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/index.htm

I have read at many places that Shanti parva and Anushasan parva were later added in the original mahabharata. Does that also make vishnu sahasranamam un-authentic?

I am sorry if there is any mistake in my question, I am new here and this is my first question.

Comment: In my opinion, such questions cannot be answered with any certainty. It is generally said by scholars that Shanti parva and Anushasana parva have lot of interpolations in them and virata parva is an interpolation. But if you look at language and style of Vishnu sahasranama, whether or not an interpolation, it appears to be one of the earliest sahasranamas. No long names, for example. So, is vishnu sahasranama an interpolation? No idea, but it seems to be pretty old.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was Vishnu Sahasranama, not a part of Anusasana Parva of Mahabharata, but a later day addition?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38811/was-vishnu-sahasranama-not-a-part-of-anusasana-parva-of-mahabharata-but-a-late)

Comment: @idolworshipper Okay, thank you.

Comment: @sv. Yes but not completely. But I guess there is no clear answer for this question. Thank you!

Comment: The [Critical Edition of Mahabharata](http://www.bori.ac.in/mahabharata_project.html) _does_ contain Shanti and Anushasana parvas and I don't think this Spitzer Manuscript was easily available when BORI was preparing the CE. Only if we could travel back in time could we really tell what was the original Mahabharata like. You can read more about the Spitzer Manuscript [here](http://www.academia.edu/attachments/33334779/download_file).

Comment: @sv. Thank you very much.