# Why did (Late) Sri K. M. Ganguli consider Anushasana Parva to be an interpolation?

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma

In the translation of [Anusasana Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/index.htm) in Mahabharata by (Late) Sri K. M. Ganguli, we see a paragraph note in the page which states:

> The Anusasana Parva, like the Santi Parva before it, is a long hiatus
> in the narrative of the Mahabharata. Set on the deathbed of Bhishma,
> the ***Anusasana Parva*** is a huge treasure-trove of Brahmanic lore which
> ***is obviously a later interpolation*** in the epic.

Why did (Late) Sri K. M. Ganguli state so?

---

**Edit 2-8-2020**

My question is different from another question , as in this question I am interested in knowing the view of the original translator  in considering ***Anushasana Parva*** to be an interpolation.

Comment: Such things happen. KMG , though a renowned scholar, was human after all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was Vishnu Sahasranama, not a part of Anusasana Parva of Mahabharata, but a later day addition?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38811/was-vishnu-sahasranama-not-a-part-of-anusasana-parva-of-mahabharata-but-a-late)

Comment: Also, see [Is Anushasan Parva from Mahabharat an interpolation? It is claimed by many scholars and also it is not mentioned in the spitzer manuscript](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40221/is-anushasan-parva-from-mahabharat-an-interpolation-it-is-claimed-by-many-schol) which is closed as opinion-based.

Comment: When asking questions, you should be extra careful about the title you choose. In the body you ask, "Why did (Late) Sri K. M. Ganguli state so?" and in the title you ask a generic question. I think you want to change the title to: "Why did K. M. Ganguli consider Anushasana Parva to be an interpolation?" - this makes the currently posted answer invalid and that's also how you defend your question against unwanted answers. If you ask ambiguous questions, you get ambiguous answers. Something to remember for your future questions.

Comment: Did he say that Adi Parva is also an interpolation?

Comment: you can check here (https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/index.htm) @hanugm

Comment: Shouldn't this be off topic? it is talking about an author (translator?) but not hinduism or its scriptures or people involved in those scriptures.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Would you like to see [another question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17558/3869) of similar nature?  Would you like to propose closing of that question also?

Comment: yes, done. Thanks. Not sure why people are diverting here.

Comment: @Mr_Green: thanks for responding.  By the way, you have forgotten to leave a comment under the question.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

In [one of the Shodhganga articles](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/142079/8/08_chapter%204.pdf), it was stated that

> It has been mentioned earlier that the Mahabharata was in the custody
> of the Brahmins of the Bhrgu race. The epic got its vast size even
> before the rise and development of the Gupta reign. The tendency to
> enlarge the Mahabharata text was still continued by these Brahmins.
>
> In their own interest, these Brahmins wrote the Puranas and rearranged
> them.
>
> It is a ***notable fact that Lord Krishna had not a prominent role***
> to play even in the first connected epic narrative.
>
> The studies of Sri [V.S. Sukthankar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu_Sitaram_Sukthankar) reveal the fact that the very
> first stanza ***'नारायणं नमस्कृत्य"*** etc. is a ***later
> interpolation*** to the Mahabharata, a pure Vaishnava composition.

---

We have to remember that Sri V.S. Sukthankar belongs to the next generation to (Late) Sri K. M. Ganguli, and thus might have read the articles of the latter.

We should revisit the words of (Late) Sri K. M. Ganguli  on Anusasana Parva:

> The Anusasana Parva, like the Santi Parva before it, ***is a long
> hiatus in the narrative*** of the Mahabharata. Set on the deathbed of
> Bhishma, the Anusasana Parva is a huge treasure-trove of Brahmanic
> lore.

Why should there be a ***long hiatus*** in the narrative of the Mahabharata, unless it was made so by later day scholars?

---

Further, the [Vishnu Sahasranama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu_Sahasran%C4%81ma) is a part of Anusasana Parva.

If we remember the observations of Sri V.S. Sukthankar - the very first stanza 'नारायणं नमस्कृत्य" etc. is a later interpolation to the Mahabharata, a **pure Vaishnava composition** - we can infer that the Anusasana Parva was included at a later date just to include Brahmanic lore and Vishnu Sahasranāma and to project Vishnu as SUPREME GOD.

---

Thus, Anusasana Parva is an interpolation, as observed by (Late) Sri K. M. Ganguli.

Comment: Lol. Did Sukthankar find a written document penned by KMG where the latter gave his reasons ? If not then the above answer is just your opinion without substance.

Comment: Nothing offensive in this answer. Just amused by you and your motivated Questions and Answers. And despite best efforts your answer does not really answer your question - "Why KMG said so n so". Might as well have said , KMG was under pressure from "modern hindus who are against any aspect of  divinity" and thus he mentioned it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112933/discussion-between-srimannarayana-k-v-and-idol-worshipper).

Comment: it is well known that the makers of BORI edition (vs sukthankar being the main editor) have a leftist bias, based on their reasoning, education and lifestyle.

Comment: Is their leaning towards Leftism only reason (or) is it due to unable to digest the fact that if Anusashana Parva is accepted as Interpolation, then Vishnu Sahasranamam will lost its ground? @ram

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV, by extension, tomorrow they can say Bhagavad Gita is also an interpolation. And then tomorrow you will remark *'will bhagavad gita losing its ground be unable to be digested by you'*. Like I said, they are leftists and their opinion can be safely ignored by those seeking truth.

Comment: Yes. I am searching for such type of content.  As I am in search of TRUTH, I don't hesitate on tomorrow, if I come across an evidence , delinking Sri Krishna from BG.   I had stated elsewhere in this site that the  insertion of episode of  Sita's fire test in Ramayana by subsequent writers led to Sri Rama's character assassination. With the same confidence I will say about SRI Krishna, @ram

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV, unfortunately, your evidence barometer for truth is set too low. anything written by western historians seems to take higher precedence i.e. you trust them blindly, compared to what is said by our acharyas.

Comment: So be it. I am answerable to myself in search of TRUTH.  I am the least bothered  as to others think about me.  Thanks for sharing your y my friend :-) @ram

Comment: @mar even in my opinion, these leftists don't understand scripture and just throw around interpolation if we continue like this there will be no scriptures left lol. I believe in rethinking/reinterpretation, putting things in another perspective or re-translation since Sanskrit words have multiple different meanings in certain cases.

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV wasn't the fire test voluntary and to prove to Rama that Sita was still his better half?

Answer (score 4):

Mahabharata contains 100 parvas which are further grouped into 18 major parvas

[Adi Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01003.htm) gives list of 100 parvas which includes Anusasana as well:

> Then comes 'Santi', then 'Rajadharmanusasana', then 'Apaddharma', then 'Mokshadharma'. Those that follow are called respectively 'Suka-prasna-abhigamana', 'Brahma-prasnanusana', the origin of 'Durvasa', the disputations with Maya. The next is to be known as **'Anusasanika'**. Then the ascension of Bhishma to heaven. Then the horse-sacrifice, which when read purgeth all sins away.
>
> ...
>
> **The high-souled Vyasa composed these hundred parvas** ...

As you can see above that **these 100 parvas including Anusasana were composed by Vayasa**.

---

The same Adi Parva chapter describes Anusasana Parva:

> Next in order is the excellent Anusasana Parva. In it is described how Yudhishthira, the king of the Kurus, was reconciled to himself on hearing the exposition of duties by Bhishma, the son of Bhagirathi. This Parva treats of rules in detail and of Dharma and Artha; then the rules of charity and its merits; then the qualifications of donees, and the supreme ride-regarding gifts. This Parva also describes the ceremonials of individual duty, the rules of conduct and the matchless merit of truth. This Parva showeth the great merit of Brahmanas and kine, and unraveleth the mysteries of duties in relation to time and place. These are embodied in the excellent Parva called Anusasana of varied incidents. In this hath been described the ascension of Bhishma to Heaven. This is the thirteenth Parva which hath laid down accurately the various duties of men. The number of sections, in this is one hundred and forty-six. The number of slokas is eight thousand.

Comment: Your answer does not answer my question,please.

Comment: "Is Anusasana Parva an interpolation in the Mahabharata?" --this is ur Q and I quoted from Mahabharata itself which denies possibility of interpolation..so why it doesn't answer ur question? U ll get answers for supporting interpolation and few denying interpolation but all answer the Q.. it's upto u or the community which one they think is right..

Comment: You should have taken the content in the question also into consideration, before answering.  I had queried in the question content - Why did (Late) Sri K. M. Ganguli state so? @YDS . By the way, the community that you have mentioned does not exist in true sense. A community will discuss or argue at length but finally reach a healthy consensus.  In this site there is no community sense, as far as I understood.  Here, we can find groupism.

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV, if you are unable to accept a valid counter-argument, that is not called 'groupism'

Comment: I have been witnessing **groupism** in this site from 2015 onwards.  So I need not provide evidence to the same again and again.  A counter argument will be provided only if there is substance in the argument.  You can downvote or flag my post :-) @ram

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV, of course there is groupism. every sect will try to enforce their values. what i'm saying is that you are using the groupism-blame to cover up your lack of providing evidence and your unacceptance of provided evidence.

Comment: I know how groupism works in this site.  It is very common for a group of members to harass and hound members like [user965167](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/18171/user965167).  It is also common for downvoting the unpleasant answers like [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36600/3869) posted by members like me and passing sarcastic remarks.   @ram

Comment: When the group of members, who follow Sri Ramanuja, could not provide evidence for claiming Narayana and Lakshmi as SUPREME God heads, from Rig Veda, Why are you asking me for showing evidence?  Further, what type of evidence are you expecting from me?  Can you explain? @ram

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV, I don't know what discussion you had earlier and who provided what evidence from where. But I have a simpler question - Why restrict your choice of evidence to ONLY Rig Veda ? Can you show proof that YOU exist from Rig Veda ?

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV, i don't see any sarcastic remarks in the ashvamedha answer you posted. I also don't see any evidence for your claim that it is an interpolation other than your assumption that ashvamedha yagna can only be for 1 purpose. putra kameshti is specifically for getting sons. ashvamedha is generally for lordship over earth. no yagna bears fruit if the doer is very sinful. so part of yagna is also prayaschitta to get rid of sins. You go from an assumption (ashvamedha yagna has 2 results mentioned) to claim (so uttara kanda is fake). It rightly deserves downvotes, although I did not.

Comment: You failed to see the sarcasm because you are also with the Idea that the Uttarakanda is not interpolation.  It is because the content in Uttarakanda suits to your Idea that Sri Rama is an incarnation of Vishnu, which is not.  Anyways, be happy alongwith other members in  your illusions and sarcasm. However, as yourself had admitted the groupism is existing in this site, and your silence regarding harassment and hounding  of members like user965167 by your group members will itself indicates the very fact that how valid my post in META about division of HSE into sect wise SEs. @ram

Comment: You took so long time to understand what my ideas are.  I should sympathize for your level of understanding. Thanks for sharing your valuable time and thoughts :-) @ram

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV check the [concerns about brigading](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1048/277)

Comment: @Pandya, SrimannarayanaKV is of the opinion that Sri Rama is NOT an avatar of Vishnu. If he posts an answer tomorrow saying that Sri Rama is avatara of Brahma, are you saying that we should categorize that under a 'different doctrinal point of view', and not downvote it ? I hope users continue to have the common sense to downvote obviously nonsensical answers.

Comment: I am not bothered much about the down voting @Pandya.  I am more concerned about harassment and hounding the members belonging to other views.  If you don't act, being a moderator, a chaotic situation will creep in and many fanatic members like the one in question, will make other normal members, take exit from the site.  It is your turn now

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV the Rig Veda Narayana Suktam calls Vishnu supreme. I suggest you pick a school before continuing ie Yoga, Samkhya, Vaisheshika, Nyaya, Vedanta, or Minamsa.

Comment: @mar, wait what Sri-Rama is Mahavishnu lol!